# unable to use fish:// in Dolphin on Fedora

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma, dolphin

I have an up-to-date Fedora 38 box but I seem not to be able to use the `fish://` protocol in Dolphin. When I enter `fish://hostname/` or `fish://IP`, all I get is the `Connecting...` and `Loading folder...` status messages on the bottom whiler I can ping & ssh to the host just fine. What's going on and how can I fix this?

I'm on:

- KDE Plasma 5.27.6
- Kernel: 6.3.12-200.fc38.x86_64
- OS: Fedora Linux 38 (KDE Plasma) x86_64